# How to use updateMany on PrismaORM and update foreign keys

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, prisma

I have a table of post and a table of users. I want to assign a list of posts to a new user. I have tried [prisma updateMany](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#updatemany) but it does not seem to work with foreign keys. How should I go on with this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible. Please see https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/2493

Answer (score -1):

Without seeing the model it's difficult to say, but traditionally it would look like this with prisma:

```
await this.prisma.posts.updateMany({
    where: {
        <conditions>
    },
    data: {
        user: {
            connect: {
                id: user.id;
            }
        }
    });
```

In my experience, it's been better to use the "connect" on the user, vs simply updating the userId field to keep FKs in check.

Comment: Prisma does not currently support this this of thing on updateMany